# KNeighborsClassifier Euclidean Distance calculation

Tags: python, machine-learning

I have a question regarding `KNeighborsClassifier`

This is the code I have for `iris`dataset.

```
iris = datasets.load_iris()
X = iris.data # Independent variables
y = iris.target # response or target or dependent variables

x_train, x_test, y_train,y_test = (train_test_split(X,y, test_size=0.3,
                                                   random_state=42,
                                                   stratify=y))

knn = KNeighborsClassifier(n_neighbors = 5)
knn.fit(x_train, y_train)
prediction = knn.predict(x_test)
print (accuracy_score(y_test, prediction))
```

So I know the distance between two points are calculated using Euclidean Distance.

For example train iris data set has 4 features and test iris data set also has 4 features so how is euclidean distance calculated between these 4 column values. Assume this is our `train` data

```
array([[5.1, 2.5, 3. , 1.1],
       [6.2, 2.2, 4.5, 1.5],
       [5.1, 3.8, 1.5, 0.3],
       [6.8, 3.2, 5.9, 2.3]]
```

And this is our `test` data

```
array([[7.3, 2.9, 6.3, 1.8],
       [6.1, 2.9, 4.7, 1.4],
       [6.3, 2.8, 5.1, 1.5],
       [6.3, 3.3, 4.7, 1.6]]
```

How is the Euclidean distance calculated for four points?

Comment: [SciPy implementation for Euclidean distance in N-dimensional spaces](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.14.0/reference/generated/scipy.spatial.distance.euclidean.html)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Same as you would for two points on a plane, or for 3 points in a 3D space - but now extended to a 4 dimensional vector space:

```
sqrt((a1-b1)^2+(a2-b2)^2+(a3-b3)^2+(a4-b4)^2)
```

This extends to any number of dimensions

Comment: So it's same even for 4 dimensional vector space. I had little doubt. When I saw the formula for Euclidean distance `sqrt((x2-x1)^2 + (y2-y2)^2`  I thought it would be different for 4 features. Thanks.